# How to set path to web.xml in Maven Jetty Plugin in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, server, jetty, pom.xml

I create a simple Spring MVC project. When I run it on the Tomcat everything work correctly, but I would like to use Maven Jetty Plugin to run it. Below a picture of project's structure:

[image]

My pom.xml file looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.journaldev.spring.mvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Spring MVC Example</name>
    <description>Spring MVC Hello World Example</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.9.v20160517</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webApp>
                        <descriptor>/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
                    </webApp>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName> <!-- added to remove Version from WAR file -->
    </build>
</project>
```

My web.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>spring-mvc-example</display-name>

    <!-- Add Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as front controller -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

 </web-app>
```

The HomeController.java file:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        System.out.println("Home Page Requested, locale = " + locale);
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);

        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String user(@Validated User user, Model model) {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested");
        model.addAttribute("userName", user.getUserName());
        return "user";
    }
}
```

The console's output:

```
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: Spring MVC Example
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory C:\Users\Tom\Downloads\spring-mvc-example\src\main\webapp does not exist. Defaulting to C:\Users\Tom\Downloads\spring-mvc-example\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = C:\Users\Tom\Downloads\spring-mvc-example\target\classes
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = C:\Users\Tom\Downloads\spring-mvc-example\target\tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = null
[INFO] Webapp directory = C:\Users\Tom\Downloads\spring-mvc-example\src\main\webapp
[INFO] jetty-8.1.4.v20120524
[INFO] No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
[INFO] No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
[INFO] started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/Tom/Downloads/spring-mvc-example/src/main/webapp},file:/C:/Users/Tom/Downloads/spring-mvc-example/src/main/webapp
[INFO] started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/Tom/Downloads/spring-mvc-example/src/main/webapp},file:/C:/Users/Tom/Downloads/spring-mvc-example/src/main/webapp
[INFO] started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/Tom/Downloads/spring-mvc-example/src/main/webapp},file:/C:/Users/Tom/Downloads/spring-mvc-example/src/main/webapp
[INFO] Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

I think that I make some mistake in configuration Jetty in pom.xml and Jetty does not see the context. Generally server has started, no errors. When I look into the console's output there is:

```
web.xml file = null
```

Some problem with Jetty Configuration in pom.xml. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your project structure, renaming from `/WebContent/` to `/src/main/webapp/`, then it will work with all Maven provided webapp services (jetty, tomcat, jboss, glassfish, etc...) including all Intellij and Eclipse IDE webapp services.

Comment: After this I have got an error: "Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]". Thanks.